# How can I save my volume adjustments?

Tags: windows-xp, audio, thinkpad

I'm using a Thinkpad T60 with Windows XP Pro SP3.

My volume control defaults to some preset which is too quiet. I want to save a higher volume, which I always adjust using the Icon in the lower, right part of my screen.

How can I alter the default?

Comment: XP's volume controls are a bit crap, 7's stick. However, AHK can do it, one moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My favorite XP Volume Control replacement:

**[Quick Mixer](http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/OS-Enhancements/Quick-Mixer.shtml)** controls Main-Volume, Main-Treble, Main-Bass and up-to 16 playback audio sources! Quick Mixer gives you access to every available playback mute on your sound-card. Quick Mixer gives you access to the first on/off check under Advanced, Other Controls.

Quick Mixer allows you to **create 10 audio profiles** and **optionally starts up with a default profile**. Quick Mixer scans your sound-card's mixer-line to offer you only the correct playback sliders.

[image]

*Quick Mixer is freeware.*

Comment: This seems much more suited to my expertise. I have downloaded it and will try it.

Thanks muchly.
Don

Comment: you're quite welcome.

Comment: Well, I downloaded it, unzipped it and it will not install. It gets to the screen where it asks if I want to change the directory or quit. The only real option is to quit?????
Perhaps I'm missing something?????

Answer (score 1):

Try an autohotkey script:

```
SoundSet, [% you want to set to]
ExitApp
```

Put that in a file with the extension .ahk, and place it in your startup folder. It'll set the volume, then exit!

Comment: Thank you. I have a few questions as I have never programmed anything but music. If I understand:
- I copy the exact information you provided, including the comma, replacing the bracketed section with the percentage I want, no comma after the number. 

Is it important for it to  be on 2 lines, as in your example?

Will this adjust all sliders or only the Master volume?

Comment: Just master volume, and yep. Important for it to be on two lines, certainly!